# PHP: Ordered List upper-alpha Style

Tags: php, html-lists

I'd like to be able to output a letter in the same way that upper-alpha ordered lists do in HTML. For example:

```
<?php

    $letter_counter = 1;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "A".

    $letter_counter = 2;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "B".

    $letter_counter = 26;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "Z".

    $letter_counter = 27;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "AA".

    $letter_counter = 28;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "AB".

    $letter_counter = 52;
    echo get_letter($letter_counter);
    // Output should be "AZ".

?>
```

It should be able to go on indefinitely. What would the code for the "get_letter" function look like? I think the code shown on [this page](http://web.powersugoi.net/articles/php-alphabet/) could be helpful, but I'm not sure how to get it to do what I want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with $letter_counter = 2; (as a number) and just simply specify the last letter that you want.

Something like this might be of interest though:

```
$letter = 'A';
$lastLetter = 'ZZZ';
$lastLetter++;
do {
    echo $letter,PHP_EOL;
} while ($letter++ !== $lastLetter);
```

(You were aware that you can increment strings as well as number, weren't you?)

Comment: Holy crap! Incrementing strings! Based on the OP's link, I'm not the only one who didn't know :) You learn something every day... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Yeah! Just watch out for the end condition... using > or < doesn't work well when you loop from Z to AA, so I always increment my end condition and use !==

Comment: But sadly, you can't decrement using --

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function, it simply converts decimal to your letter base (=base 27, 26 letters plus 0 which we prevent from outputting)

```
function get_letter($n)
{
    $n += floor($n/27); //fixes missing 0s

    //characters to be found in base_convert return string
    $convert = '123456789abcdefghijklmnopq';

    $out = '';
    foreach( str_split(base_convert($n, 10, 27)) as $char )
    {
            $out .= chr(strpos($convert, $char)+65);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

For designating columns in a spreadsheet (eg Excel column names) or similar, this function may be better suited to do what you want.